# iTunes won't open after update

Tags: macbook-pro, itunes, error

My iTunes will not open under my username after an update.  It pops up an error message saying "iTunes will not open. An unknown error has occurred (13001)".  However, I tried troubleshooting it from the Apple website and got no where except I know it works under a different user.

Can I fix my iTunes without having to delete it?

Comment: What exactly did you update?

Comment: My computer updated iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

Reading [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1705959) and [this article](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203349), it seems as if your library is corrupt.

Follow the recommendations and instructions from the above linked official support article for error 13001.

Comment: I tried this which is how I discovered that iTunes opens on the computer under another user; however after that step I'm lost.